# How can I clean up this ugly if statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following ugly if statement that is part of a class that is pulled from an IOC container:

```
protected virtual void ExecuteSourceControlGet(IBuildMetaData buildMetaData, IPackageTree componentTree)
{
    if ((buildMetaData.RepositoryElementList != null) && (buildMetaData.RepositoryElementList.Count > 0))
    {
        componentTree.DeleteWorkingDirectory();

        foreach (var repositoryElement in buildMetaData.RepositoryElementList)
        {
            repositoryElement.PrepareRepository(componentTree, get).Export();
        }

    }

    if((buildMetaData.ExportList != null) && (buildMetaData.ExportList.Count > 0))
    {
        var initialise = true;

        foreach (var sourceControl in buildMetaData.ExportList)
        {
            log.InfoFormat("\nHorn is fetching {0}.\n\n".ToUpper(), sourceControl.Url);

            get.From(sourceControl).ExportTo(componentTree, sourceControl.ExportPath, initialise);

            initialise = false;
        }

    }

    log.InfoFormat("\nHorn is fetching {0}.\n\n".ToUpper(), buildMetaData.SourceControl.Url);

    get.From(buildMetaData.SourceControl).ExportTo(componentTree);
}
```

My normal approach to eliminating if statements is to create a subclass for each condition.

What is different about this example is:

1. The class that has this method is pulled from the IOC container.
2. I might want the logic in between the 2 if statements to run or not at all.

Any advice greatly welcomed.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to eliminate anything?  And adding subclasses just to get rid of an 'if'?  I can understand  what your code does easily, therefore it is highly readable. No reason to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using two *extract methods*, and invert the if's to be guards:

```
protected virtual void ExecuteSourceControlGet(IBuildMetaData buildMetaData, IPackageTree componentTree)
{
   ExecuteRepositoryElementList(buildMetaData.RepositoryElementList, componentTree);

   ExecuteExportList(buildMetaData.ExportList, componentTree);

   log.InfoFormat("\nHorn is fetching {0}.\n\n".ToUpper(), buildMetaData.SourceControl.Url);

   get.From(buildMetaData.SourceControl).ExportTo(componentTree);
}

private void ExecuteRepositoryElementList(RepositoryElementList repositoryElements, IPackageTree componentTree)
{
   // Guard: No elements
   if (repositoryElements == null || repositoryElements.Count == 0) return;

   componentTree.DeleteWorkingDirectory();

   foreach (var repositoryElement in repositoryElements)
   {
      repositoryElement.PrepareRepository(componentTree, get).Export();
   }
}

private void ExecuteExportList(ExportList exportList, IPackageTree componentTree)
{
   // Guard: No elements
   if(exportList == null || exportList.Count == 0) return;

   var initialise = true;

   foreach (var sourceControl in exportList)
   {
      log.InfoFormat("\nHorn is fetching {0}.\n\n".ToUpper(), sourceControl.Url);

      get.From(sourceControl).ExportTo(componentTree, sourceControl.ExportPath, initialise);

      initialise = false;
   }
}
```

BTW: The two methods must be fixed with the correct type of **IBuildMetaData.RepositoryElementList** and **IBuildMetaData.ExportList**.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not really sure why you'd want to eliminate the if statements - and using inheritance for it seems over the top. You might want to create an extension method for the repeated collection code:

```
public static bool HasElements<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
{
    return collection != null && collection.Count != 0;
}
```

This lets you change the conditions to:

```
if (buildMetaData.RepositoryElementList.HasElements())
```

and

```
if (buildMetaData.ExportList.HasElements())
```

which is slightly simpler IMO. If there ends up being any more logic you might also want to separate the two blocks into different methods. Other than that, I wouldn't worry.

Oh, and another extension method which won't help if you need to care whether or not you have elements, but will help if you just want to do a null-safe `foreach`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

(Not that it saves very much over using the null coalescing operator inline, admittedly...)

Comment: That's what I thought too. Can't see anything really wrong with those if-statements

Answer (score 0):

```
protected virtual void ExecuteSourceControlGet
    (IBuildMetaData metaData, IPackageTree tree)
{
    if (metaData.RepositoryElementList.HasElements())
    {
        tree.DeleteWorkingDirectory();

        foreach (var element in metaData.RepositoryElementList)
             element.PrepareRepository(tree, get).Export();    
    }

    if(metaData.ExportList.HasElements())
    {
        var init = true;

        foreach (var sourceControl in metaData.ExportList)
        {
            log.InfoFormat
              ("\nHorn is fetching {0}.\n\n".ToUpper(), sourceControl.Url);

            get.From(sourceControl)
              .ExportTo(tree, sourceControl.ExportPath, init);

            init = false;
        }

    }

    log.InfoFormat
       ("\nHorn is fetching {0}.\n\n".ToUpper(), 
           metaData.SourceControl.Url);

    get.From(metaData.SourceControl)
       .ExportTo(tree);
}

//Credits goes to Jon Skeet...
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static bool HasElements<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        return collection != null && collection.Count != 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either create an extension method as John suggested, or either (if this makes sense in the context of the rest of your class) refactor it and make buildMetaData a member of the class and have two private bool properties with a get that masks your dual clause if statement with something more readable.

Either way accomplishes the same result of making it more readable.